# JPA, merge objects updating childrens

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I´ve got this on the parent object

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="idUser", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public List<Directions> directions;
```

And in my controller I´ve got this

```
public static void userUpdate(String apikey, JsonObject body) {
    if(validate(apikey)) {

        Long idUser = decode(apikey);
        User oldUser = User.findById(idUser);

        Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<String, User>();
        Type arrayListType = new TypeToken<Map<String, User>>(){}.getType();
        userMap = gson().fromJson(body, arrayListType);
        User user = userMap.get("user");

        oldUser.em().merge(user);

        oldUser.save();

    }else{
        forbidden();
    }
}
```

It makes the update on the parent object but when I change something on the children object it doesn't update it and neither gives problems with hibernate or Oracle.

Does anyone know why it doesn´t update the child object?

Thanks all!

## Updated with solution!

This is how it works for me, as @JB Nizet said you´ve got to save the child objects too.

```
oldUser.em().merge(user); 
oldUser.save();

for (Direction direction : oldUser.directions) { 
    direction.save();          
}
```

## Another aproach!

With this

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "SASHNBR", insertable = true, updatable = true)
public List<Direction> directions;
```

I´ve been able to make oldUser.save() and get the child objects saved.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530498/jpa-persisting-object-parent-is-ok-but-child-not-updated

Comment: @rayyildiz I did, if you look at the code I implemented the CascadeType.MERGE which is the one I want. Anyway I will try with CascadeType.ALL. Thanks! :)

Comment: @rayyildiz didn't work either. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Play requires a call to `save()` on all the modified entities. So you probably need to iterate through the user's directions and save them as well:

```
for (Direction direction : user.getDirections()) {
    direction.save();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, that was all that I needed. For more detail:

   oldusuario.em().merge(usuario);
   
   oldusuario.save();
  
   for (Direccion direccion : oldusuario.direccion) {
       direccion.save();
   }